# How to get the name of a function?

Tags: erlang

Is it possible to know the name of a function in itself ?

```
a_function()->
    io:format("I am ~p!", [????]). % What to use here?
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the macro `?FUNCTION_NAME` to get the name of the current function as an atom, and `?FUNCTION_ARITY` to get the arity as an integer.

Example:

```
-module(test).

-export([a_function/2]).

a_function(_Foo, _Bar) ->
    io:write("I am ~p/~p!",[?FUNCTION_NAME, ?FUNCTION_ARITY]).
```

```
1> c(test).
{ok,test}
2> test:a_function(a, b).
I am a_function/2!
```

This was implemented in [EEP-0045](https://www.erlang.org/erlang-enhancement-proposals/eep-0045.html).

**For Erlang Versions 18 and Older**

In older Erlang versions, there's no simple way to get the current function name at compile time. You can however retrieve it at runtime:

```
{current_function, {M, F, A}} = process_info(self(), current_function)
```

Where `A` is the arity (number of arguments), not the actual arguments. The first argument to `process_info/2` is a process ID which can be either the current process (`self()`) or an other process. For example:

```
1> process_info(self(), current_function).
{current_function,{erl_eval,do_apply,5}}
```

Note however, that while this would be functionally equivalent to the `?FUNCTION_NAME` macro, it's much slower because it is evaluated in runtime.

Comment: `?FUNCTION_NAME` and `?FUNCTION_ARITY` macros now exist: http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/macros.html#id85926

Answer (score 5):

at runtime, you could throw an exception and check the top of the stacktrace.

```
foo() ->
    catch throw(away),
    [{Module, Fun, Arity} | _] = erlang:get_stacktrace(),
    io:format("I am ~p:~p/~p!~n",[Module, Fun, Arity]).
```