# Erlang - How to find the name of current function at runtime?

Tags: function, erlang

Can I find the name of the current function I'm in at runtime?

```
foo() ->
  foo = find_function_name().
```

Is it possible to write the fun find_function_name/0? 
How would you do it? Does it already exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the name of a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915339/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-function)

Answer (score 3):

More lightweight and also not depending on the stacktrace format which can change occasionally, I'd rather use `process_info/2`:

```
{_, {Module, Function, Arity}} = process_info(self(), current_function)
```

In `Function` you'll find the function name as an atom and you get the `Module` and the `Arity` also.  You can't write this as function because it would just return this function as current.  A macro that gives you the current function name as atom could look like:

```
-define(current_function_name(), 
            element(2, element(2, process_info(self(), current_function)))).

foo() ->
    foo = ?current_function_name().
```